# Exponent of a sum of martingales

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I have a question about checking the integrability of the following function:

$Z_{n}=e^{X_{n}+Y_{n}}$ where $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are both martingales w.r.t. a filtration $F_{n}$. I know that I have to look at $E[Z_{n}]<\infty$ but I don't see how.

Comment: Why the deliberate duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

I think we cannot prove integrability without further assumptions on the $X_n$s and $Y_n$s.

If $\varphi$ is a concave function and $X,Y\in L^1$, then $\varphi(X),\varphi(Y)\in L^1$ by Jensen's inequality.

However, the exponential function is convex. For instance, if the PDF of $X$ is $f_X(x)=e^{-x}$, supported on $\mathbb{R}^+$, the PDF of $Z=e^X$ is $f_Z(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$, supported on $[1,+\infty)$. In such a case $X\in L^1$ and $e^X\not\in L^1$.